# change path dialog file browser in ckfinder using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ckfinder

I have a silly question about ckfinder.  On tab upload, we can select a file using the dialog.

My question is: can I change path on dialog, because it always return to `C:\user\downloads\`, I need to change it to another path simply like `D:\myimages\`

Comment: Don't think it can be done, it depends of the client's last opened folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the config-file (ckfinder/config.ascx) there are two path settings:
BaseUrl - "this is the relative path, e g where the files are, for example '/userfiles/' "
and
BaseDir - "this is the absolute path to disk, for example 'D:\Folder\Another\Subfolder\'

If BaseDir is empty it tries to resolve the BaseUrl.

Read more here: http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Configuration/Quick_Start